# NGRX correct usage of store selectors

Tags: angular, ngrx, ngrx-store

I am using Ngrx in my application to store the state. 
Let's say my store has two items itemA and itemB. 
My componentX reacts to change in itemA and triggers a function which further does some more complex calculations which requires the current value of itemB

```
ComponentX {
    pi = 3.15;
    date = new Date();
    constructor(private appStore: Store<AppState>){}
    ngOnInit() {
         this.appstore.select(selectItemA).subscribe(
             (itemA) => someComplexFunction(itemA)
         )
    }
    someComplexFunction(itemA) {
        /* Requires itemB */
    }
}
```

The componentX however doesnt care when the itemB changes, it only requires the current value of itemB when itemA changes. I cannot remove itemB from my state as it is required by other components. 
What is the correct approach to write a selector in this case.

Comment: You can subscribe to itemA selector, and pipe it through `withLatestFrom` wiith the itemB selector

Comment: Can you give us some more info regarding `someComplexFunction`? Is it a pure function or does it have side effects? If it's a pure function then you should totally write another selector for it.

Comment: @maxime1992: it is not a pure function

Comment: Dee zg answer's is the right one then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you could make use of `withLatestFrom` operator.

something like `withLatestFrom(this.appstore.select(selectItemB))` which will give you the `B`.

take a look at this example where the same thing is done in effects:
https://gist.github.com/vteivans/da5adf19a94da9e32d27cb8b9d5b8884

(principle is the same)

Comment: Below code is give undefined for val this.appstore.select(selectItemA).pipe(withLatestFrom(selectItemB)).subscribe((val) => console.log(val))

Comment: I realized the error got it to working now. Thanks for the help